# DAX measure to calculate the time spent in a call per time bucket

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need a measure that will calculate, for every time bucket, the total amount of time employees spend on calls.

Time buckets are as follows:

| Bucket | Start | End | HourofDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7:30-8:00 | 7:30 | 8:00 | 1 |
| 8:00-9:00 | 8:00 | 9:00 | 2 |
| 9:00-10:00 | 9:00 | 10:00 | 3 |
| 10:00-11:00 | 10:00 | 11:00 | 4 |
| 11:00-12:00 | 11:00 | 12:00 | 5 |
| 12:00-13:00 | 12:00 | 13:00 | 6 |
| 13:00-14:00 | 13:00 | 14:00 | 7 |

These time buckets exist in a Time table.

For examples sake, here's a a tiny sample set for the calls

| Start | End | Duration | StartHourofDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7:30 | 7:50 | 20 | 1 |
| 7:45 | 7:50 | 5 | 1 |
| 7:50 | 8:15 | 25 | 1 |
| 8:15 | 10:23 | 128 | 2 |
| 9:20 | 9:45 | 25 | 3 |

Typically, I would do a simple `CALCULATE(SUM(Calls[Duration]))` but this results in incorrect values:

| Bucket | Expected SumofCallDurations | incorrect Result using formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7:30-8:00 | 35 | 50 |
| 8:00-9:00 | 60 | 128 |
| 9:00-10:00 | 85 | 25 |
| 10:00-11:00 | 23 | null |

I assume this would require building a virtual table of some sort but I'm at a loss as to how to do so...

Comment: Does start hour of day mean anything? What's the Dax formula you currently have? I presume you see it's currently based on start time...?

Comment: How do you count a call that crosses multiple time periods? (like the 8:15-10:23 call.... do that call count once for each time period it occurs in (8, 9, 10) )

Comment: The math works out to being exactly by the minute so for the 7:30 to 8:00 range you have `20+5+10` from the top three lines which equals 35.

Comment: @Pieter per the example, the 8:15-10:23 call counts as one call that contributes 45 minutes to the 8:00-9:00 bucket, 60 minutes to the 9:00-10:00 bucket and 23 minutes to the 10:00-11:00 bucket.

Comment: @pgSystemTester The 35 minutes is exactly what I put in the expected results. The start hour of day is the index of the hour in the day hence all minutes from 7:30-8:00 belong to the first hour in the day, all minutes from 8:00-9:00 belong to the 2nd hour of the day and so on

Comment: @Sweepster, yeah I know... see solution.

Answer (score 0):

What if you created a Time table with every minute in the workday with the associated time bucket? (tiny - there are only 1440 minutes per day so that's super easy!) Then your start time would have a bucket, and your end time would too, and then you just filtered for all times in between and just returned a count of callID's per bucket?

Then your total buckets per call is just [EndBucket] - [StartBucket] + 1. right?

(Might be time for some list magic)

Comment: But I don't want to count the number of buckets per call, I want the total amount of minute each call spends in each time bucket.

Comment: you don't have to count them... once you've split the call time into a series of time spans, you calculate whatever stats you like.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to establish these as a dimension/axis member rather than a measure so that you can have these axis on various graphs. Assuming so, you'd probably be best to conduct this in Power Query while grabbing your data.

To avoid repititive lines of code to calcute the buckets of time, create a  custom function that calculates how many minutes are in a specified windo of time based on a start and end time. This can be accomplished in below code for formula I made calle `getMinutesInTimeRange`

```
let
   getMinutesInTimeRange = (startTime as time, endTime as time, bucketStart as time, bucketEnd as time) =>
   if startTime > bucketEnd then 0 else if endTime < bucketStart then 0 else
   let 
        zEnd = if endTime > bucketEnd then bucketEnd else endTime,
        zStart = if startTime < bucketStart then bucketStart else startTime,
        finalNumber = zEnd-zStart
   in
      finalNumber
in
   getMinutesInTimeRange
```

so it should like this when done:

[image]

You then can just create each of these as a column in your data table and then branch them off via an unpivot.

I took your data and made made a hard coded table, adding one more shift to add full set of numbers to each bucket

[image]

Then using below Query formula, created this table showing each bucket (I added one more to account for afternoon).

[image]

Query Formula (won't work without custom function named `getMinutesInTimeRange`

```
let
    zRawTable = #table(
     {"Start","End"},{ { "7:30", "7:50"},{ "7:45", "7:50"},{ "7:50", "8:15"},{ "8:15", "10:23"},{"4:00","14:00"},{ "9:20", "9:45"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(zRawTable,{{"Start", type time}, {"End", type time}}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type" , "b_0730_0800", each getMinutesInTimeRange([Start], [End], #time(7, 30, 0), #time(8, 0, 0))),
    #"Invoked Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "b_0800_0900", each getMinutesInTimeRange([Start], [End], #time(8, 0, 0), #time(9, 0, 0))),
    #"Invoked Custom Function2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function1", "b_0900_1000", each getMinutesInTimeRange([Start], [End], #time(9, 0, 0), #time(10, 0, 0))),
    #"Invoked Custom Function4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function2", "b_1000_1100", each getMinutesInTimeRange([Start], [End], #time(10, 0, 0), #time(11, 0, 0))),
    #"Invoked Custom Function5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function4", "b_1300_1315", each getMinutesInTimeRange([Start], [End], #time(13, 0, 0), #time(13, 15, 0))),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function5", {"Start", "End"}, "Bucket", "Minutes"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Start", "End"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns1", each [Minutes] <> 0),
    #"Calculated Total Minutes" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Minutes", Duration.TotalMinutes, Int64.Type }}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Calculated Total Minutes", {"Bucket"}, {{"Minutes", each List.Sum([Minutes]), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: But this doesn't work... if I have a slicer to select which day I want to look at, the number of minutes in each bucket should change based on the calls made on that day. Your method of doing in power query makes it impossible.